# How to solve matric question containing exponents

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I am stuck on this matrix question as it contains complex numbers as exponents and I don't know how to go about it if anyone can guide me or show a worked solution it will be a massive help. Thanks in advance.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVequ.png)

Comment: We you are asked to multiply out $2 \times 2$ matrices, note that $e^{ j \theta} e^{-j \theta} = 1$ and $e^{j \theta} = \cos \theta + j \sin \theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain some complex numbers.

Consider the imaginary plane to have an $x$-axis consisting of the real part of the imaginary number and the $y$-axis consisting of the imaginary part. ie $3+4i$ is just the point (3,4).

in light of that consider polar coordinates. The angle $\theta$ is measured anticlockwise from from the positive real axis and the radius is as expected, both of which can be calculated with simple trigonometry.

Hence a complex number may be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is the radius, and $e^{i\theta}= cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$. I will leave you to prove this yourself using trigonometry and various Taylor expansions.

Now onto your question.

For $AB$ note that $e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}=(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))(cos(-\theta)+isin(-\theta))=(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))(cos(\theta)-isin(\theta))=cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)=1$

now apply this to the $2\times 2$ matrix you have and you should be fine!

Comment: I am confused here because of the complex number in front of the exponential as exponential is another way of writing complex numbers as far as I understand. But I don't understand what to do when there is both a complex number and exponential

Comment: so for example $\frac{1}{2}(1+j)e^{-j\theta}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-j)e^{j\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1+j)(1-j)e^{-j\theta}e^{j\theta}=\frac{1}{4}(1-j^2) = 0$ since $j^2=-1$